# Finding the true expectation

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I have the density function and I want to determine its expected value

```
f[x_] :=0.8000064000512005` (0.25`/(1 - x)^3 + 0.5`/(1 - x)^2) UnitStep[-x] + 0.8000064000512005` (0.25`/(1 + x)^3 + 0.5`/(1 + x)^2) UnitStep[x]
```

I used

```
Limit[NIntegrate[f[x]*x, {x, -y, y}], y -> Infinity]
```

which gives $0$

unlike

```
NIntegrate[f[x]*x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Then I used

```
z[x_] := ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Mean[z[x]]
```

which was running and running..

What is the right way? what is the expected value w.r.t. the given density function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] = 4/5 *
    ((1/(4 (1 - x)^3) + 1/(2 (1 - x)^2)) UnitStep[-x] + (1/(4 (1 + x)^3) + 
       1/(2 (1 + x)^2)) UnitStep[x])//FullSimplify;

f[1] = f[1.] = Limit[f[x], x -> 1]
```

> 1/8

```
f[-1] = f[-1.] = Limit[f[x], x -> -1]
```

> 1/8

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> {0, .625}]
```

[image]

Verifying that the distribution integrates to one:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 1

```
Expectation[1, Distributed[x, dist]]
```

> 1

Since the distribution is symmetric about zero the mean is zero.

```
f[-x] == f[x]
```

> True

```
Mean[dist]
```

> 0

```
Expectation[x, Distributed[x, dist]]
```

> 0

Comment: Thx for the answer.